# Currently there are two options for development on the Playbook

Tags: air, blackberry-playbook, qnx-neutrino

I am trying to figure out if there are plans for a third, pure C/C++ or java SDK for the Playbook.

Anyone know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there are plans for both.  However both are scheduled for later on after the official launch with an ETA of Summer 2011 (details came from the 2011 Developer Day in Toronto yesterday.)

This also includes the tools to port Android Apps to run in the "Android App Viewer".

***Update:*** The schedule has changed a bit but there is now more information available about the upcoming "BB 10" platform expected around February/March of 2012. (Note it was originally called "BBX")

BB 10 Announced: http://crackberry.com/bbx-announced-devcon-2011-today

Developers interested in developing on the new platform can gain *early* access here: https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/native/

Comment: Just to clarify, they actually haven't told us about any "native Java" support yet... only for the Java support for running Android and BBOS apps inside a special "app player".  We're still waiting on any official plan for Java for "native" PlayBook apps, on par with, say, the AIR support.

Comment: @PeterHansen: Android apps aren't Java.  They aren't Java bytecode, and run on Dalvik, not a JVM.  And they don't support the standard Java class library.  The only "Java" involved is the language syntax.

Comment: @BenVoigt, thanks very much for the info, which changes nothing in my answer, nor adds to the discussion, as far as I can see. Dalvik may not be "the" JVM but it's still a VM, for code which as you say was written in Java source. I don't see any point in what you wrote.

Comment: @PeterHansen: If you wanted to run an existing Java application or library, rather than simply write new applications using Java syntax, the difference would matter very much.

Comment: @PeterHansen as Blackberry provide a Java ME SDK (Blackberry JDE) for their legacy platform it may be prudent to mention plans (or comments) for both Android as well as Blackberry JDE.